# Making private attributes in Python classes

Tags: python, class, attributes, private

**I want to restrict access of private attributes only to chosen methods.**

I mean I don't want public class to contain private attributes.
Which means, either way, one need to have another class to hold those attributes.
Although, just having public and private classes separated doesn't provide straight access.
Unless, you bind them yourself.

**Taking above into account, I have made working prototype.**

Bases:

```py
# Auto-binding of private classes to public classes.
class RemoteMeta(type):

    # Access to private classes via public class-names.
    _classes = { }

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        rv = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

        if bases[0] is not object: # Ignore 'Remote' class.

            # Access to private class-instances via public class-instances.
            rv._instances = { }

            # Add private class reference.
            cls._classes[name[1:]] = rv

        return rv

    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        # Since attribute is not present in private class,
        # look for it in public class.
        return getattr(cls._cls, name)

# Auto-binding of public instances to private instances.
# Auto-binding of private instances to public instances.
class Remote(object, metaclass=RemoteMeta):

    def __new__(cls, inst, *args, **kwargs):

        if cls is Remote:
            detail = "'{}' class is not meant to be used directly".format(cls.__name__)
            raise TypeError(detail)

        v = object.__new__(cls)

        # ???
        v.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Access to public instance from private instance.
        v._self = inst

        # Add private instance reference.
        cls._instances[inst] = v

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Since attribute is not present in private instance,
        # look for it in public instance.
        return getattr(self._self, name)

# Auto-binding of public classes to private classes.
class PublicMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        rv = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

        if bases[0] is not object: # Ignore 'Public' class.

            # Access to public class from private class.
            Remote._classes[name]._cls = rv

        return rv

# Auto-creating of private instances for each new public instance.
class Public(object, metaclass=PublicMeta):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        rv = object.__new__(cls)

        if cls is Public:
            detail = "'{}' class is not meant to be used directly".format(cls.__name__)
            raise TypeError(detail)

        # Create private instance.
        Remote._classes[cls.__name__](rv, *args, **kwargs)

        return rv
```

Descriptors:

```py
class RemoteClassMethod:
    [...]
            return self.method(
                Remote._classes[owner.__name__],
                *args, **kwargs
            )
    [...]

class RemoteInstanceMethod:
    [...]
            return self.method(
                Remote._classes[owner.__name__]._instances[inst],
                *args, **kwargs
            )
    [...]

class RemoteProperty:
    [...]
        return self.fget(
            Remote._classes[owner.__name__]._instances[inst]
        )
    [...]
```

**Is given code a valid way to implement such a thing?**

I mean, are there any serious drawbacks?
Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: We don't do [codereview.se] here; "is this a valid way to implement X?" is not a proper specific question for our standards.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "Also is there a way to fix 'RemoteProperty' descriptor?" Code Review doesn't fix broken code.

Comment: @Peilonrayz The point is well taken. There are two separate questions here; the one you highlight could be on topic here, if it is a) asked by itself and b) properly specified (in order to "fix" something, we must understand exactly what is broken about it, and what should happen instead when it is used).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have cut not relevant code. and I have moved out second question to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77142496/custom-property-decorator-with-external-lookup)