# Custom @property decorator with external lookup

Tags: python, class, properties

I have made custom @property decorator which should return attribute from external instance, or from internal instance.
But when attribute is missing in both instances I get recursion error.

```
class X(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(y, name)
        
class Y(object):
    @property
    def var(self):
        self = x # Custom property returns `x` instead of `self`
        return self.var
        
x, y = X(), Y()

print(y.var)
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How can I fix it without changing 'var' property, and without removing access to 'y' from 'X'?

**Edit:**

I was hell bend on preventing recursion error from happening.
But it works as it should.

I mean it only happens when 'X' object has no attribute that is named same as property.

Which translates to:

```
class Y(object):
    @property
    def var(self):
        return self.var
        
y = Y()

print(y.var)
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

It could only use better error description like:
`RuntimeError: 'Y' object property 'var' points to itself`, but there is no place to put try/except block before recursion.
So I will let it be.

Comment: You have built your instances to be mutually recursive.  What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @quamrana They are not mutually recursive, only property makes it that way. I want "AttributeError: 'Y' object has no attribute 'var'"

Comment: But `class Y` has property `var`.